# using double equal operator with boolean

Tags: java, equals

So, I'm facing finals next week and I went through some old tests. This one caught my attention because I can't seem to understand the code.

```
public class Start {
   boolean zustand = false;

    public static void main (Strings[] args){
        Start obj = new Start();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            if(obj.getZustand() == true){
                System.out.println(""+i+ " true");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(""+i+ " false");
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean getZustand(){
        zustand = (zustand == false);
        return zustand;
    }
}
```

I thought the output would be

```
0 true
1 true
2 true
3 true
```

but I tried them on eclipse and the output is

```
0 true
1 false
2 true
3 false
```

Can anyone please explain to me why they're not all true?

Comment: zustand = (zustand == false); What do you think this line does?

Comment: That is a finals exam question? What kind of school are you attending?

Comment: You tried this on Eclipse? Did you think about setting a breakpoint?

Comment: That `getZustand()` method hurts, I hope they are atleast teaching you that you should never change values in getters. Even though I'm wondering why they are doing it themselves if they are teaching you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `zustand` variable is changed every time the `getZustand` function is called.

```
zustand = (zustand == false);
```

This line of code is the same as `zustand = !zustand`. And notice that `zustand` is a class member field, so its value is kept across function calls.

Comment: This is the only answer so far pointing out that this could have been `zustand = !zustand`.  (It wouldn't hurt to mention `zustand ^= zustand`, as well.)

Comment: now I get it! I thought the method getZustand() doesn't change the value of zustand permanently, so that every time the iteration goes, the zustand value returns to false. Thank you everyone!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The first iteration sets the member variable `zustand` to true; `false == false` is `true`. The second iteration sets the variable to `false`; `true == false` is `false`. Then they alternate as you posted.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `zustand` is alternating each time you call `getZustand()`. This is because you are assigning `zustand` with first `false == false`, which is `true`, then `true == false`, which is `false` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

```
zustand = (zustand == false);
```

- If `zustand` is **`true`**, then `zustand == false` is `false` and `zustand` is assigned to **`false`**.
- If `zustand` is **`false`**, then `zustand == false` is `true` and `zustand` is assigned to **`true`**.

In other words, the line `zustand = (zustand == false)` flips the value of `zustand` (which is then returned). This explains your output.

Answer (score 0):

Every time getZustand is called, the value of the Boolean in obj is flipped.

To achieve the output you want, simply return (zustand == false),  or more simply, (!zustand).